# Is it good to give food or drinks to a toddler at night after weaning off breast milk?

Tags: toddler, night-time, weaning

I am in the process of weaning my toddler from breastfeeding. At the moment he still drinks milk (breastfeeds) at night. Once he stops breastfeeding completely, what should I do if he wakes up and seems hungry at night? Is it OK to offer milk, juice, or cereal?

Comment: "At night" as in "during the night" or as in "before bedtime"? And welcome to the site!

Comment: And how old is your child?

Comment: Nancy, welcome to Parenting.SE. We will need a bit more information about your child's age and the timing of the additional foods to give you a good, clear answer. Also, what information are you looking for when you say "good" -- healthy, important, good habits? Can you please **[edit]** to clarify?

Comment: we used to mix a tiny bit of rice cereal at the last bottle-feeding of the night for our daughters to have extra sustenance to sleep the night.  Part of sleeping through the night is metabolism.  I'm surprised that there aren't "sleep-the-night" formulations for baby-formula.  It is about having a little body-mass and a little nutrition - then it is about training habits.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly OK to offer food or drinks at night, but [teeth need to be brushed afterward.](http://www.webmd.com/oral-health/guide/what-is-baby-bottle-tooth-decay)

You might decide to wean your child off eating at night in order to get uninterrupted sleep for baby and uninterrupted sleep for you too!  According to [Ferber](https://books.google.com/books?id=soY1FV4ft8cC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Ferber&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMIq8SY4r2jyAIVhR0-Ch2bwQb5#v=onepage&q=Ferber&f=false) and my personal experience, in weaning off night feeds, when done gradually, your toddler will get used to not having a meal at that time. Eventually the hunger will shift to other times of day.

I weaned off breastfeeding at night, and replaced it with formula or whole milk for the first couple weeks when my toddler was waking for her middle of the night feed; I would reduce the amount in the bottle each night. I found that to be easier than cutting down on nursing time (putting her back in bed after 5 minutes of nursing made her really mad and awake).  But if the bottle only had a small amount in it, that was easier for her to accept.

Maybe that technique will work for you too.  At 18 months, we only give her water at night; she wakes maybe once night per week asking for water.

Answer (score 0):

A snack before bed, brush teeth, then off to bed. If they wake at night offer a bottle of water. 
With one of my children the night waking was so constant that I finally placed a bottle of water in her crib at night, she would wake, find it and drink a bit, then dose off again. When she moved into a bed the bottle was replace with a sippy cup of water.